# Port forwarded but still can't connect to XAMPP

Tags: apache, ip, xampp, port, portforwarding

I can't connect to my localhost via my public IP address. When I try to, the browser can't establish the connection.
I have successfully forwarded port 80, which I confirmed through http://www.canyouseeme.org/.
I tried reinstalling XAMPP but it didn't work.
I could connect without problems before I changed my standard router for a wifi router. So I think that's the problem.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What OS? what Router? you may also want to post you httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your xampp is listening on port 80.  You also need to make sure the server has port 80/443 open on the firewall for the wireless adapter.